# Need help regarding ORMLite using android. foreignAutoRefresh not working

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

Can somebody provide an example regarding ORMLite with `foreign = true`, `foreignAutoRefresh = true` using android? A small project in android would be much helpful.

I am trying to create a parent child relationship where child would be provided to parent as a `memberField`. Later if parent queried by eg: `parent.queryForAll()`, as auto-refresh enabled need not to be queried again.

However, when I query like this I get child is `null`.  When enabling `foreign = true`, is the id field automatically set for child or we need to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are forgetting to add the child object to the database.  The typical pattern is to store the child object to the database using its own DAO and then set the child on the parent before persisting the parent to the database.  The child does not get automatically written to the database.  There is a [`foreignAutoCreate = true`](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-auto-create) feature that was added recently that will help with this.

There are a number of examples on the website for [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  Do none of them work?  We've spent a long time on the documentation.  Have you looked at it at all?

> http://ormlite.com/docs/examples

The foreign collection example is a good one to take a look at.  There are also working Android examples.

> http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples

Comment: Hi Gray, Thank you for your quick reply. Somehow I missed to see that foreign collection example. Now working on it. Will get back you soon. Thank you